# Как вызвать экшн обычного контроллера из консольного контроллера Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как вызвать экшн обычного контроллера из консольного контроллера?

Есть уже готовый экшн в обычном контроллере \yii\web\Controller, который работает с несколькими моделями и формирует на их основе файлы. Я хочу вызвать этот экшн из консольного контроллера \yii\console\Controller. Как мне это сделать?

Пробовал методы:

1. `$this->runAction('controller/action');` - вызывает экшн только внутри этого контроллера, т.е. выбрасывает ошибку:

   > Error: Unknown command "controller/action"
2. `$this->run('controller/action');` - то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас встает такая задача, значит, вы неправильно приготовили MVC.

Контроллеры - это просто участки кода, которые берут входные данные, преобразовывают их во внутренние и вызывают сторонний код, после чего просто форматируют полученный результат (в основном, конечно, через представление). То есть вся задача контроллера - это превратить HTTP-запрос или консольный запрос в некоторый внутренний запрос, отдать его обработчику, получить результат обработки и превратить его в HTTP-ответ или консольный вывод. За непосредственно обработку данных контроллер не отвечает, поэтому у вас просто не должна возникать задача создания единого контроллера - весь потенциально дублирующийся код и так должен быть где-то внутри написанного для указанной задачи сервиса, а консольные, веб- и прочие контроллеры должны просто вызывать его.

Таким образом задача решается не через написание прослойки, пытающейся устоять сразу на двух видах входных данных, а через написание единой прослойки, которую тянут два (или больше) контроллеров. Написание похожего или даже дублирующегося кода в этом случае допустимо, потому что обеспечивает возможность изменить один из интерфейсов приложения, не трогая другой.

Comment: Да, именно так и сделал. Спасибо за хороший ответ. Он лучше моего. Пожалуй, не хватает только примера, как это лучше сделать. Добавите?

Comment: @Razzwan боюсь, никогда не писал на втором Yii

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, чтобы использовать консольное приложение, надо в начале сделать его.

Т.е. Необходимо создать контроллер в какой-либо папке (по умолчанию лучше делать в `console/controllers`), унаследовав его от базового класса для консольных приложений `\yii\console\Controller`, а далее в консоли происходит вызов:

`yii controllerName/actionName [входные параметры, если есть]`.

Пример:

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Console;

class TestController extends \yii\console\Controller {

    public function actionHello() {
        echo  'Hello, world!';

        return 0;
    }  


    public function actionInput($someVar) {
        echo  'Hello, '.$someVar.'!';

        return 0;
    }  
}
```

Если написать в консоли `yii test/hello`, то в консоли выведется `Hello, world!`.

В экшн `input` можно передать параметр:

`yii test/input world` тоже выведет `Hello, world!`

По поводу вызвать обычный контроллер, который что-то берет у модели.

Можно было бы написать, что можно в экшне консольного приложения создать экземпляр класса контроллера - там где то обращаться еще что-то через маршруты, но...

В данном случае, думаю, уместнее будет сделать как раз необходимую обработку тут. Также обратившись к необходимой модели, чтобы не дублировать логику (в случае если из обычного контроллера это тоже должно быть доступно). Либо если логика доступна только для консольного приложения, может быть туда всё и вынести.

Но, так или иначе, для начала необходимо сделать класс именно консольного приложения.

Comment: За ответ спасибо. Может, кому-то пригодится, но не мне. Решил через объявление общего экшена для двух контроллеров: консольного и обычного.

Comment: @Razzwan Да, запамятовал, что можно так делать в `yii2`. Могу это написать в ответе :-D   Но вообще, чтобы не оставлять вопрос открытым, раз есть решение, то можете сами опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Я могу только через 3 дня свой ответ опубликовать. На вопрос ответ не нашел, но решил задачу тем, что создал общий для двух контроллеров экшн. Поместил в общей папке common. Наследовался от yii\base\Action

Comment: @Razzwan да я знаю на счет общих экшенов)) Это не мне ответ нужен, а другим пользователям будет полезен. Поэтому желательно тут ответ правильный оставлять и отмечать его. Поэтому два вариант либо мне дополнять ответ и вы голосуете за, либо сами просто как сможете опубликовать ответ - опубликуете и отметите. Главное чтоб он был и был полезен остальным. Ждем вас =)

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу тем, что создал общий экшн для двух контроллеров. [Вот ссылка на документацию](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-controllers/#standalone-actions), как это сделать.

С одной стороны удобно, что экшн отдельно. Он общий для нескольких контроллеров и логично, что он находится в отдельном месте.

Но с другой - это не совсем решение поставленной задачи, так как предполагает более сложный подход (копипаст), чем простое использование уже готового кода.

Если есть более простое решение в рамках yii2 - приму обязательно.