# Как создать консольную команду в yii2?

Tags: yii2

В yii первой версии было легко создать консольную команду. Но как это сделать в yii 2 версии? Там есть пример в /commands/HelloController.php, но как отталкиваться от него?

Comment: поможет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482628/191482

Comment: вот тут подробно расписано http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html#create-command

Comment: Вы уточните в чем именно у вас проблема, а то не совсем понятно. Вроде как `HelloController` очень нагляден...